# Edible straws that look like plastic ones

Tags: candy

I'd like to make some root beer float cupcakes. [The recipe](http://www.bhg.com/recipe/layer-cakes/root-beer-float-cupcakes/) suggests garnishing them with a decorative (non-edible) straw. But I'd like to kick things up a notch: is there such a thing as an edible straw that looks sufficiently like a drinking straw (i.e. same width, preferably striped like an old soda fountain straw)?

I know there are various edible straw-like things available, but they all seem noticeably wider that a drinking straw. I don't require that they be hollow inside, but the width is my main concern.

Comment: What is it about the thickness that's the problem?

Comment: I should clarify that by thickness/width (I just changed it to width in my question) I mean the outer diameter of the straw-like object. I just want something that looks like a drinking straw and not, e.g., a tubular biscotti-like thing.

Comment: I always used Red Vines/Twizzlers for straws but they're still wider in diameter. But they're more colorful.

Comment: Does it have to actually be a straw?  I know one of the shops near me sells chocolate cigarettes, which might work (depends on the ambient temperature), but you'd have to add the stripe yourself.

Comment: That might work. I'm not sure about pairing chocolate with the root beer, but I know those cigarettes also come in generic sugar flavor.

Comment: How long do you intend the fake straw to last? Almost everything edible+solid is water soluble.

Comment: It doesn't have to last more than a few days.

Comment: [This](http://www.bustle.com/articles/80023-starbucks-cookie-straws-arent-the-only-edible-straws-around-try-these-7-options-too) might be useful reading, though it seems most of its suggestions have already been brought up here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Stick candy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stick_candy) would be an option. They even usually offer it in many flavors including [root beer](http://www.candywarehouse.com/products/old-fashioned-hard-candy-sticks-root-beer-80-piece-box/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=Shopping&utm_term=%7Bkeyword%7D&gclid=CLbtj_3TscsCFY-DaQodWMYCYQ) or [sassafras](http://www.candywarehouse.com/themes/old-fashioned-and-nostalgic-candy/products/old-fashioned-hard-candy-sticks-sassafras-80-piece-box/). Obviously, the root beer flavored ones are sort of boring looking but the other flavors come in many beautiful color combos.

[image: Root Beer Candy]

They may be slightly wider than what you want but they're pretty close. They're similar to the wider straws for shakes.

Comment: I couldn't come up with the American term, but as the OP appears to be from the US that should do the trick.

Comment: I was thinking vanilla flavour might work of you can find it. It would have that artificial vanilla ice cream flavour that would go with root beer.

Comment: This is what I went with. They have several flavors (with corresponding colors) at Cracker Barrel.

Comment: You could sand them down if size is a **big** concern, not too easy though

Answer (score 14):

[image]

Pirouette cookies (here by Pepperidge Farm) are rolled wafer cookies. The inside is stuffed with chocolate, chocolate hazelnut or vanilla.

Here's a [recipe](http://www.dianasdesserts.com/index.cfm/fuseaction/recipes.recipelisting/filter/dianas/recipeid/1559/recipe.cfm) that includes a picture using them in a manner similar to what you're asking.

[image: 2]

You could follow the recipe, but tweak it to look more like a straw and with colors and flavors that suit your purpose.

Comment: This is what our local soda fountain gives us in our shakes.  They don't work very well as actual straws, but visually they give that appearance - so perfect for something where they don't need to be actual straws :)

Comment: Thanks -- that was one specific thing I was thinking of, albeit one that I think is too wide, but couldn't remember the name of.

Comment: Making them to look like straws and with a flavor that goes with your theme could be a really fun project :)

Comment: In the comments on the question, the OP seems to not want a cookie-type thing, though I may be misunderstanding.

Comment: The only problem I have with cookie-/biscotti-like treats is that they're fairly wide.

Comment: @echristopherson Would you consider making them?

Comment: @Jolenealaska Possibly, but for this project I've finally picked something out.

Answer (score 11):

[Pocky](http://www.gotchocolate.com/2011/01/review-pocky-chocolate-cream-covered-biscuit-sticks/) is probably about the right diameter, but doesn't have that spiral of color that would really *look* like a straw.

[image: Photograph of Pocky box and a Pocky, from a blog review of the product]

[Candy Sticks](http://www.bogdonschocolates.com/) look right, but the available flavors might not be a great match for your root beer cupcakes.

[image: Photograph of candy sticks dipped in chocolate, from the manufacturer]

Comment: Wow -- if there's something like the Bogdon's sticks without chocolate covering, that would just about do it. It's not optimal that the stripes are lengthwise, but that's OK; real straws usually have those stripes now.

Comment: I think Pocky is definitely the way to go. They come in quite colourful version, such as [banana (yellow)](http://www.oyatsubox.com/wp-content/uploads/Choco-Banana.jpg) or [strawberry (pink)](http://www.thirstyfortea.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/pocky-boxes2.jpg) which should make quite a convincing straw.

Comment: @echristopherson If I was just making it for me, I'd lick the chocolate off... but that really isn't an option when cooking for others :)

Comment: Upvoted because Pocky is the right answer for everything

Answer (score 6):

I was considering rolling chocolate or fondant and lo and behold some googling turned up these fondant straws made for use atop cupcakes, along with instructions on how to make them:

https://bakearama.wordpress.com/2014/05/09/pink-lemonade-cupcakes/
[image]

The short version:  Twist together "snakes" of red and white fondant to make straws.  They will harden as the fondant dries.

Comment: A C, welcome! Have you ever clicked on a link and received a "this site no longer exists" message? That's *exactly* why we discourage "link only" answers here. Could you please at least paraphrase the main steps, so in case of link rot your answer stays useful?  That said, you might want to take the [tour] and visit our [help] to learn more. Welcome to Seasoned Advice!

Comment: From experience making candy-cane shaped cookies ... make both snakes a little thicker than your intended final diameter.  Place the two side by side and roll them around until it looks like it's once stick (not just two things twisted together).  As you're rolling, occassionally push one side while pulling the other to get some twist into it.  Once it's well bonded, adjust the twist (as best you can, it takes some practice), finish rolling out to the desired thickness, and cut to length.

Answer (score 4):

It's the wrong flavour but something like a candy cane with the curved part cut off might look the part.

I've seen many flavours of seaside rock sold in some shops, I *think* including the thin type about the diameter of a straw. This is in the UK, I'm not sure whether you can get it where you are.

Anywhere calling itself an "old fashioned sweet shop" or selling fudge cut up to order would be worth a try. A quick look online didn't show sensible quantities.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like a product called "[lollistraws](http://www.lollistraw.com/Default.aspx)" by squire boone village might work. They're lolipops shaped as drinking straws.

I do wonder if you can take some homemade candy cane or lolipops, dip them on a lubricated/foiled dowel and then pull out the dowel. Or more insanely, a small cylinder of ice.

Comment: Note: Lollistraws are wholesale only. They look good though.

Comment: Yeah. But I'd guess theres someone who resells them.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that just after logging off. Yes, there are retailers with them.